# How can one set a screen timeout longer than 10 minutes on Android 13 with a Samsung Galaxy S23?

Tags: android-13, screen-timeout, samsung-galaxy-s-23

I don't see any options in the developer options. The [Caffeine](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=moe.zhs.caffeine) application doesn't keep the screen on. How can one set a screen timeout longer than 10 minutes on Android 13 with a Samsung Galaxy S23?

---

By default, 10 minutes is the maximum:

[image]

The Caffeine application has an infinite setting but that doesn't work:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked developer settings? I have seen devices that had an option to disable screen timeout. Be aware that an increased timeout can destroy your OLED screen  (ghost images).